# Ipad on Fullscreen losses css style

Tags: jquery, css, ipad

I have customized HTML5 player with control bar on top to input comments,bookmark created using jquery.
it works fine in window when seen in fullscreen but in case of Ipad on fullscreen that control bar is not visible.
I want to prevent the Ipad native player on fullscreen and play my customized HTML5 player.
My script as follows--

```
function OsBrowserDetection(referrer) {
var OSName = "Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) OSName = "Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) OSName = "Mac";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11") != -1) OSName = "Unix";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux") != -1) OSName = "Linux";
var BrowserName = mejs.MediaFeatures.isFirefox ? "Firefox" : mejs.MediaFeatures.isChrome ? "Chrome" : mejs.MediaFeatures.isIE ? "IE" : mejs.MediaFeatures.isWebkit ? "Safari" : "IE";
var isTabletOrPhone = (mejs.MediaFeatures.isAndroid || mejs.MediaFeatures.isiOS);
var BrowserVersion = 0
if (BrowserName == "Firefox") {
    BrowserVersion = ($.browser.version < 21.0) ? "20-" : "21+";
}
if (!isTabletOrPhone) {
    checkPlayerExceptionMatrixAndInvokePlayer(BrowserName, BrowserVersion, OSName,referrer);
}
else {
    invokePlayer(DefaultPlayer);
}
}

function invokePlayer(playerName) {
if (playerName == "Silverlight") {
        $("#divSilverlightPlayer").show();
    $("#HTMLPlayer").hide();
    $("#HTMLPlayer").html("<div></div>");
}
else {
    $("#divSilverlightPlayer").hide();
    $("#divSilverlightPlayer").html("<div></div>");
    $("#HTMLPlayer").show();
    invokeHTMLPlayer();
}
}



function FullScreenClassChange() {
$('#Content').removeClass('maxcontent');
$('#Content').addClass('content');
$('#top_row_right_contents, #top_row_right_bookmarks, #top_row_right_search,    #media_icon_description, #media_icon_Transcript, #media_icon_TagCloud, #media_icon_RelatedVideos, #media_icon_UserCmnts').removeClass('top_row_right_divs');
$('#top_row_right_contents, #top_row_right_bookmarks, #top_row_right_search, #media_icon_description, #media_icon_Transcript, #media_icon_TagCloud, #media_icon_RelatedVideos, #media_icon_UserCmnts').addClass('top_row_right_divs_left'); ;
$('.top_row_right_divs_left').height($('#myVideo').height() - '10' + 'px');
$('#inner_content, #inner_bookmark,#inner_search,#inner_description,#inner_Transcript,#inner_TagCloud,#inner_RelatedVideos,#inner_UserCmnts').height($('#myVideo').height() - '40' + 'px');
$('.commentDiv').height('66%');
$('.usercmtspopup').height('70%');
$('.popupComments').height('55%');
$('#top_row_right').appendTo('#top_row');
$('#top_row_media_div').appendTo('#container');
$('#top_row_right_contents, #top_row_right_bookmarks, #top_row_right_search,         #media_icon_description, #media_icon_Transcript, #media_icon_TagCloud, #media_icon_RelatedVideos, #media_icon_UserCmnts').appendTo('#player_outer');
$('#top_row_right').removeClass('top_row_right_fullscreen');
$('#top_row_media_div').removeClass('top_row_media_div_fullscreen');
$('#top_row_right').show();
}

var chckfullscreen = '';
var ua = navigator.userAgent,event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";
$('.mejs-fullscreen-button').live(event, function () {
chckfullscreen = $('.mejs-fullscreen-button').attr('class');
if (chckfullscreen == "mejs-button mejs-fullscreen-button mejs-fullscreen") {
    $('#Content').removeClass('maxcontent');
    FullScreenClassChange();
}
else if (chckfullscreen == "mejs-button mejs-fullscreen-button mejs-unfullscreen") {
    windowheight = screen.height - '60' + 'px';
    innerheight = screen.height - '100' + 'px';
    $('#top_row_right').appendTo('.mejs-inner');
    $('#top_row_right_contents, #top_row_right_bookmarks, #top_row_right_search, #media_icon_description, #media_icon_Transcript, #media_icon_TagCloud, #media_icon_RelatedVideos, #media_icon_UserCmnts,#top_row_media_div').appendTo('.mejs-inner');
    $('#top_row_right').hide();
    $('#Content').removeClass('content');
    $('#Content').addClass('maxcontent');
    $('#top_row_right_contents, #top_row_right_bookmarks, #top_row_right_search,       #media_icon_description, #media_icon_Transcript, #media_icon_TagCloud, #media_icon_RelatedVideos, #media_icon_UserCmnts').height(windowheight);
    $('#inner_content, #inner_bookmark,#inner_search,#inner_description,#inner_Transcript,#inner_TagCloud,#inner_RelatedVideos,#inner_UserCmnts').height(innerheight);
    $('.commentDiv').height(screen.height - '300' + 'px');
    $('.usercmtspopup').height(windowheight);
    $('.popupComments').height(screen.height - '300' + 'px');
    $('#top_row_right_contents, #top_row_right_bookmarks, #top_row_right_search, #media_icon_description, #media_icon_Transcript, #media_icon_TagCloud, #media_icon_RelatedVideos, #media_icon_UserCmnts').removeClass('top_row_right_divs_left');
    $('#top_row_right_contents, #top_row_right_bookmarks, #top_row_right_search, #media_icon_description, #media_icon_Transcript, #media_icon_TagCloud, #media_icon_RelatedVideos, #media_icon_UserCmnts').addClass('top_row_right_divs'); ;
    $('#top_row_right').addClass('top_row_right_fullscreen');
    $('#top_row_media_div').addClass('top_row_media_div_fullscreen');
    $('#top_row').show();
    $('#top_row_right').show();
    $('#txtInnerSearch,#txtBookmarks,#txtUserName,#txtComment').click(function (e) {
        if (chckfullscreen == "mejs-button mejs-fullscreen-button mejs-unfullscreen") {
            if (this.id == "txtBookmarks") {
                myPlayer[0].player.pause();
            }
            $('.mejs-fullscreen-button').trigger('click');
            $('#' + this.id).focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $('.maxcontent').mouseover(function () {
        $('#top_row_right').show();
    });
}
});
```

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated..
I followed http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/jquery-click-events-ipad to resolve fullscreen issue but still not resolves.